# How do you authenticate aws s3 authentication version 4 requests, in node.js?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm following this guide: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-header-based-auth.html

And I'm having a difficulty at the last step, where you use the signing key to create the signature.

This step of the first GET example:

```
signing key = HMAC-SHA256(HMAC-SHA256(HMAC-SHA256(HMAC-SHA256("AWS4" + "<YourSecretAccessKey>","20130524"),"us-east-1"),"s3"),"aws4_request")
```

does not have the resulting signing key, so I don't know if it's right. Instead of the signature
`f0e8bdb87c964420e857bd35b5d6ed310bd44f0170aba48dd91039c6036bdb41` I am getting `f03131e53fcdcd3605054f5ead58370d14a672add94bda5da0a69d65d03e7edc`.

Can someone tell me what the signing key for the example is? I think it is the step that I'm missing.

I can post my 253 lines of express.js code upon request. The step before this, where I get the string to sign (`7344ae5b7ee6c3e7e6b0fe0640412a37625d1fbfff95c48bbb2dc43964946972`) is correct.

Comment: I think the official [aws-sdk](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js) or the popular [knox](https://github.com/LearnBoost/knox) package abstract this for you.

Comment: The solution was to use 'buffer' for encoding in the intermediate HMAC steps

Comment: please add an answer with the details and accept it, so others can benefit of it

Answer (score 0):

The correct signing key of the example is `dbb893acc010964918f1fd433add87c70e8b0db6be30c1fbeafefa5ec6ba8378`.

It is important (but only noted on a [different page of the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html#signing-request-intro)) that you use the raw buffers for calculating the signing key, and that you pass a raw buffer to the HMAC function that calculates the final signature.

Or, as pseudocode, given that the third parameter of the `hmac(key, msg, format)` function allows you whether you want to get a hexadecimal string or a raw byte array:

```cpp
Buffer dateKey = hmac(('AWS4' + secretAccessKey).toBuffer(), date, 'buffer');
Buffer dateRegionKey = hmac(dateKey, region, 'buffer');
Buffer dateRegionServiceKey = hmac2(dateRegionKey, 's3', 'buffer');
Buffer signingKey = hmac2(dateRegionServiceKey, 'aws4_request', 'buffer');

print("SigningKey\n" + signingKey.toHex());

String signature = hmac(signingKey, stringToSign, 'hex');

print("Signature\n" + signature);
```